# Port redux state to component state when the component mounts (without need for GET request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a form in a React/Redux application that is used to update information - hence require the fields to be pre-populated with current data.

Before the component is mounted, the data for the form is already sitting in Redux state.

Currently, within the `componentDidMount()`lifecycle, an axios GET request is sent to retrieve the information from the database again and loads it into the redux state.

This method works fine, however I would like to avoid the additional/redundant GET request as the information is already in the redux state.

How do I port the redux state to the component's state when it loads, so that the input fields are populated (without the need for the GET request)?

component code is below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Navbar from '../components/layout/Navbar';
import Sidebar from '../components/layout/Sidebar';
import Breadcrumbs from '../components/layout/Breadcrumbs';
import TextFieldGroup from '../components/form-components/TextFieldGroup';

import { getPatientById } from '../redux/actions/patient.actions';

class PatientEdit extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (this.props.match.params.patient_id) {
      this.props.getPatientById(this.props.match.params.patient_id);
    }
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }

    if (nextProps.patients.patient) {
      const patient = nextProps.patients.patient;
      this.setState({
        firstName: patient.firstName.patients,
        lastName: patient.lastName.patients
      });
    }
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e, patient_id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // boring script to handle form submission...
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    const { patient } = this.props.patients;

    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="app-body">
          <Sidebar />
          <main className="main">
            <div className="container">
              <form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e, patient._id)}>
                <div>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    value={this.state.firstName}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="lastName"
                    value={this.state.lastName}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Link to="/patients" className="btn btn-light mr-2">
                    Cancel
                  </Link>
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

PatientEdit.propTypes = {
  getPatientById: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  patients: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  patients: state.patients,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPatientById }
)(PatientEdit);
```

**getPatientById action**

```
export const getPatientById = id => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setPatientLoading());
  axios
    .get(`/api/patients/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PATIENTS_SINGLE,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but where is the axios call?

Comment: That is performed in a redux action `getPatientById()`. That is called in the `componentDidMount()`. The view prior is a profile of the patient, hence the action was called on the previous page and all the patient's information is already stored in redux. This view renders a form to update that information, but recalls the action to get the data it already has!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are copying the data from redux to local state. That might be needed, or not. As for your goal, why not directly render the data received from Redux (without copying them to state)? In that case, you can skip the axios call in `componentDidMount`.

If you want to have data from Redux in state anyway, you could copy them to state in constructor or in `componentDidMount`. This makes the copy only once though. If you then need to keep data from redux and state in sync, you need to ensure this in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

I believe the problem you encountered with your current set up is that `componentWillReceiveProps` isn't called for first render, hence nothing was copied to your state.

Comment: I use the local component state to manage the input fields (this is how the `onChange` and `onSubmit` methods work - they're based on local state). I don't need the two states to be in sync, I just need to get Redux into local component state when it mounts to pre-populate the fields. How would I refer to the redux state within the `constructor()`? I have thought of this but can't find any resources that discusses.

Comment: @Braden Same way you would refer to them anywhere else: `props.smth`? (And make constructor signature as `constructor(props)`)

Comment: Ahh... I tried that... But I didn't put `props` into the constructor call. Clearly I've had enough coding for today. All is working now - thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

On a remount, couldn't you pass down Redux state and use that for control logic? I am assuming it comes from `patients` Redux state as you're using it in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method, so if that is the case, couldn't you do:

```
// rest of code emitted for brevity
componentDidMount = () => {
    // assuming init state for patients.patient is null
    if (!this.patients.patient && this.props.match.params.patient_id) {
      this.props.getPatientById(this.props.match.params.patient_id);
    }
  };
```

This assumes `this.props.patients.patient` initial state is `null` from the reducer. If `this.props.patients` is null instead, then change the control logic code to be `!this.props.patients && this.props.match.params.patient_id`.

The control logic here is saying "If patients is null and we have the param ID then make the API GET call". If you already have the patient, then it won't bother.